# gitlab ci/cd runner stuck

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gitlab-ci-runner

I have droplet with installed gitlab omnibus server, gitlab-runner and docker.
Trying to configure runner to rebuild and run docker container on every push to master branch. 
Following to gitlab's instruction:

[image]

I registered runner:

```
$ sudo gitlab-runner register
Runtime platform                                    arch=amd64 os=linux pid=8665 revision=3afdaba6 version=11.5.0
Running in system-mode.

Please enter the gitlab-ci coordinator URL (e.g. https://gitlab.com/):
http://example.com/
Please enter the gitlab-ci token for this runner:
ru7i9G9R-3BJn2RXKdtv
Please enter the gitlab-ci description for this runner:
[ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-fra1-01]: warehouse
Please enter the gitlab-ci tags for this runner (comma separated):
warehouse
Registering runner... succeeded                     runner=ru7i9G9R
Please enter the executor: parallels, ssh, virtualbox, docker+machine, kubernetes, docker, docker-ssh, shell, docker-ssh+machine:
docker
Please enter the default Docker image (e.g. ruby:2.1):
warehouse:latest
Runner registered successfully. Feel free to start it, but if it's running already the config should be automatically reloaded!
```

Here is config.toml file generated on runner registering:

```
$ sudo cat /etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml
concurrent = 1
check_interval = 0

[session_server]
  session_timeout = 1800

[[runners]]
  name = "warehouse"
  url = "http://example.com/"
  token = "f5b8036463e2f97d2ab4bc721b6a91"
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "warehouse:latest"
    privileged = false
    disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
    oom_kill_disable = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/cache"]
    shm_size = 0
  [runners.cache]
    [runners.cache.s3]
    [runners.cache.gcs]
```

Runner is alive:

```
$ sudo gitlab-runner verify
Runtime platform                                    arch=amd64 os=linux pid=9417 revision=3afdaba6 version=11.5.0
Running in system-mode.
Verifying runner... is alive                        runner=f5b80364
```

Then I ran it:

```
$ sudo gitlab-runner run
Runtime platform                                    arch=amd64 os=linux pid=9678 revision=3afdaba6 version=11.5.0
Starting multi-runner from /etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml ...  builds=0
Running in system-mode.

Configuration loaded                                builds=0
Listen address not defined, metrics server disabled  builds=0
Listen address not defined, session server disabled  builds=0
```

Gitlab see that runner:
[image]

But when I push to master pipeline stucks:
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

This is `.gitlab-ci.yml` file in project I try to pipeline:

```
build_image:
  script:
    - docker stop warehouse warehouse_redis
    - docker-compose build
    - docker-compose up -d
```

If I build this on server manually everything works well.

So on pushing runner just stucks without any information about issue.
Did I miss anything? Help me please. I want to run ci/cd pipelines on same with gitlab server droplet. But want to edit sources on local PC using IDE.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looks like your gitlab-runner is not configured to run untagged jobs. The runner is registered with the `warehouse` tag.

You can configure the gitlab pipeline to use the `warehouse` tag (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html#tags):

```
build_image:
  script:
    - docker stop warehouse warehouse_redis
    - docker-compose build
    - docker-compose up -d
  tags:
    - warehouse
```

Comment: awesome! Now it reacts on pushing!